# Dynamic replacing of a fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know there are a lot of posts about this but I just cant find a solution.
I'm trying to replace fragments on an activity dynamically, i have followed lots of tutorials and posts here and I got stuck in one exception:

" must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener"

I have looked for it but I'm honestly getting really tired of this.

More specifically the exception occurs in the `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);` line, it must be something i missed on the main activity but I cant see it.

here is some of my code..

```
public class LoggedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private FrameLayout fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged);

    this.setTitle(R.string.app_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logged, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Consultas) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment fragment = new ConsultasFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Trans) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Pagos) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Telefono) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Creditos) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Mapa) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

my container activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_logged"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_logged"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_logged_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my fragment activity

```
public class ConsultasFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ConsultasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ConsultasFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ConsultasFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ConsultasFragment fragment = new ConsultasFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultas, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

xml...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.ConsultasFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Most of this code was generated automatically by Android studio.

Comment: Your `Activity` must implement `ConsultasFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener`, which it currently doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `LoggedActivity` declaration to

```
public class LoggedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ConsultasFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Then Override this method in `LoggedActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    // Whatever you would like your activity to do when your fragment calls this
}
```

The point here is that you need to provide a mechanism for your `Fragment` to interact with your `Activity`, by calling `mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri)` in your `Fragment`, you can call your `Activity` to do whatever you require.

Comment: Exeption is not showing anymore, however my fragment doesnt seem to get loaded, what exactly am i supposed to do with this method?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your `ConsultasFragment`, you'll see this `interface` method:

```
/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Either implement this method in the `activity` to which you are attaching the `fragment`, or if you don't need this `interface` (which is mainly there so that the `fragment` can interact with/pass data to and from the calling `activity`), simply remove it from the `fragment`.